# Как нарисовать график функции между двумя горизонтальными границами?

Tags: python, matplotlib

У меня есть сложная функция, состоящая из нескольких кусочных, поэтому чтобы не писать сюда много кода предлагаю разобрать проблему на простой синусоиде. Есть 2 горизонтальные границы, которые функция не должна пересекать. При достижении этой границы график становится равным этой границе до того времени пока функция не начнет убывать. И также в случае возрастания. На рисунке попытался изобразить, что хочу получить.
Прошу заметить значение графика равно верхней границе только пока функция возрастает(!!!), а не когда значение больше этой границы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой график функции выглядит так, и невозможно предугадать в какой точке будет пересекаться с любой из границ. Все зависит от исходных данных
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
x = np.arange(0, 25, 0.1)
y = np.sin(x)
uppery = 0.5
lowery = -.5
# украшательство
plt.plot(x, y, alpha=0.3)
plt.axhline(uppery, color = 'lightgreen')
plt.axhline(lowery, color = 'lightgreen')
projx1 = np.arange(np.pi/2, 25, np.pi*2)
projx2 = np.arange(1.5*np.pi, 25, np.pi*2)
plt.vlines(projx1, ymin = uppery, ymax = max(y), color="r", linestyles="dashed")
plt.vlines(projx2, ymin = lowery, ymax = min(y), color="r", linestyles="dashed")

# собственно решение - прибавление или вычитание разницы между локальными экстремумами 
# и ограничмтельными линиями в зависимости от возрастания/убывания функции
func1 = func2 = y
if uppery < max(y):
    func1 = y-(max(y)-uppery)

if lowery > min(y):
    func2 = y+(lowery - min(y))

res = np.where(np.diff(y, prepend=[0])<0, func1, func2)

res = np.clip(res, lowery, uppery)
plt.plot(x, res, color="r")
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При значениях ограничительный прямых, превышающих экстремумы, функция просто отрисовывается без изменений
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при неравных разностях ограничительных прямых график все равно будет ломаться, потому что одним сложением/вычитанием координат тут не отделаешься - нужно будет перерассчитывать точки.

Comment: Супер! Спасибо, то что надо)

Comment: С одной оговоркой, если например uppery = 2 и lowery = -2 график ломается, но все же это лучше чем ничего)

Comment: Ну график ломается по вполне понятным причинам - достаточно добавить проверку, что экстремумы не пересекают горизонтальные прямые, и все.

Comment: я дополнил ответ.

Comment: Красиво! Хотя я так и не понял, что собственно тут требовалось. Но главное вы поняли и нарисовали )

Comment: @CrazyElf, спасибо, главное я понял, когда эта красота не будет работать  - нужно будет дописывать код, но это уже нюансы, с которыми автор вопроса сам справится, я думаю)

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно вас понял, то можно использовать [numpy.clip](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html):

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

n = 100
x = np.linspace(0, np.pi * 4, n)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y, 'b--')
y1 = np.clip(y, -0.5, 0.5)
plt.plot(x, y1, 'r')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, но не совсем так. В момент когда синусоида находится в верхней точке и начинает убывать, тогда и красная линия тоже убывает до нижней границы. Затем когда достигает нижней точки и начинает возрастать красная линия тоже возрастает до верхней границы. Тем не менее спасибо, изучу np.clip поподробнее.

Answer (score 0):

Ну на первый взгляд - не так уж сложно.

На каждом шаге считаете разницу для входных данных с предыдущим значением

```
dy = in_y - in_y_last
```

Если достигнут max и dx>0 (функция возрастает), в выходные данные записываем max, иначе, похоже по описанию, прошлое выходное значение `out_y_last+dy`. Аналогично с min